# How to reduce browser tab size in gnome-fallback?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, gnome-classic, gnome-tweak-tool

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using gnome-fallback. The tab size of both Chrome and Firefox are annoyingly large. How can I reduce the size? 
I've installed `gnome-tweak-tool` but could not figure out what are the relevant settings.

Comment: Here you go https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/683962. Obviously, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Read the question carefully.